# Parent Relationship Conditional -- if not empty

Tags: relationships, conditionals, advanced-conditionals

I have had no luck in trying to sort a conditional that will only show the following if the category is not empty for the parent relationship.

```
<h3>ARTICLES</h3>
{parents orderby="date" sort="desc" channel="articles" category="1" status="not closed"}  
  <h4><a href="{parents:title_permalink="articles/view"}">{parents:title}</a></h4>
  <h5>{parents:article_author}</h5>
{/parents}
```

This is an online magazine table of contents. The parent relationship is the issue number. So I want to only displays articles in the TOC if there are any for that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
{parents orderby="date" sort="desc" channel="articles" category="1" status="not closed"}  
  {if parents:count == "1"}<h3>ARTICLES</h3>{/if}
  <h4><a href="{parents:title_permalink=">{parents:title}</a></h4>
  <h5>{parents:article_author}</h5>
  {if parents:no_results}{/if}
{/parents}
```

Regard's.